# Drawing a graph on android

Tags: android, graph, android-canvas

I want to draw a graph on my android app. I did some reading and found out that using a canvas I can draw anything I want on the android app.

I am looking for a canvas which runs with a predefined time (say 10 seconds) as X-axis and draw the waveform which defines the Y-axis. I would want to get values out the graph drawn too.

Any library that I can employ? Is using a canvas the only option or do I have other options?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a library for this. Your requirement seems simple and could be accomplished by writing a custom view. You can utilize the `onDraw(canvas)` to draw the graph. You can use a `Handler` to post the x/y coordinate (run it every 10 seconds), or by any other means. A custom view is an excellent option to keep things modularized and you could get the graph at any time via `getDrawingCache()`.